# java for loop with empty statements

Tags: java

I have seen following pattern in some java code recently. Can somebody explain it to me? What does this for loop mean?

```
for (;;) {
    try {
        // do something     
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof SomeException) {
            break;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: any resolution on this, there's been so many answers already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will make an endless loop, so you need a break to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

tldr; `for(;;) {..}` is semantically equivalent to `while(true) {..}`.

---

Without an "end condition" the `for` loops forever .. or until a `break` or `return` or propagated exception or JVM termination. (With this type of loop, which is equivalent to `while(true) {..}`, the other parts of the `for` are also omitted as they are not used.)

In this case there is a `break` that is invoked if and only if a certain type of exception was caught. Otherwise the code will keep looping where it presumable retries a particular operation again and again while ignoring some types of exceptions. (This might be a case of a "clever programmer" using exceptions for flow control..)

---

Annotated:

```
// loop "forever" ..
for (;;) {
    try {
        // .. and perform some action ..
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof SomeException) {
            // .. but terminate the loop on a certain exception ..
            break;
        }
        // .. or otherwise loop again (even on an exception)
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given no "break" statement, that loop will loop indefinitely. A "break" statement leaves a loop, regardless of what the exit condition is.

The code block you have there will keep doing the thing in the "Try" block until a SomeException is thrown. Once a SomeException is thrown, the loop will exit. Checking to see if a SomeException is thrown can't be done within the declaration of the loop, so the loop is told to loop forever. Then the condition under which the loop ends is specified within the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to something like this:

```
 while(true) {
     try {
         // Do something
     } catch(Exception e) {
         if(someCondition)
             break;
     }
 }
```

The loop will run until it is explicitly broken by the exception handler.

Notice that this (and your `for(;;)`) will be running forever if `someCondition` is never set to `true`.

If you insist to do this endless loop, I would modify it to something like:

```
boolean terminateLoop = false;
while(true) { // for(;;) {
    try {
        // Do something
        if(someTerminationCondition)
            terminateLoop = true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        if(someCondition)
            break;
    } finally {
        if(terminateLoop)
            break;
    }
}
```

**Note.** I wouldn't use this on any real world algorithm... it is just a "theoretical" solution to avoid an endless loop.

The `for` loop is meant to do things based on specific increments (or decrements) of a variable... I like to call it a "deterministic" loop (I'm not quite sure if it is an appropriate name). If whatever you need to do doesn't gives you a way to use specific increments (or decrements) of a variable as a break condition, I think you should consider using `while` or `do... while` loops (which I like to call "non-deterministic" loops).

Answer (score 0):

If means the it will continuously loop and perform the actions stated in '//do something' until an instance of 'SomeException' is thrown, in which case the loop will terminate.

They are commonly used in network socket programming, when an application is listening in on a port, and terminates if there are errors.

**Explaination**

It is a infinite loop, or similar to a 'while(true)' loop statement.

'for' loops are defined as

```
for([variable declaration]; [ending condition]; [action to do at the end of each loop]){...}
```

As you can see, with a 'for(;;)' No ending condition is specified and it loops on forever. A 'break' is a must in such a loop to prevent the infinite loop when certain conditions are met.

Personally I don't like using them too much unless absolutely necessary. While there is no significant performance disadvantages (see [why does an infinite loop of the unintended kind increase the CPU use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846165/why-does-an-infinite-loop-of-the-unintended-kind-increase-the-cpu-use)), one has to be very careful when changing the code inside the infinite for loop, so it does exit eventually with a 'break'.